# Using generated interaction in multiple regression

Tags: r, regression, statistical-significance, multiple-regression

I have 20 predictors consist of categorical and numerical type. Categorical variables have more than 20 levels. When I check for correlation between numeric predictors and target, it shows no or very weak linear relationship.

I run a regression using all variables and I got.

```
    mod1 <- lm(Absenteeism.time.in.hours~.,trainData)
Call:
lm(formula = Absenteeism.time.in.hours ~ ., data = trainData)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-6.5735 -1.0466  0.0035  0.9400 10.4666 

Coefficients:
                                Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)                      6.01680    1.28457   4.684 3.72e-06 ***
Reason.for.absence3              0.60749    2.56512   0.237 0.812897    
Reason.for.absence5             -0.96714    1.59901  -0.605 0.545586    
Reason.for.absence6             -2.13411    1.23030  -1.735 0.083481 .  
Reason.for.absence7             -2.35854    1.04951  -2.247 0.025098 *  
Reason.for.absence8             -2.29507    1.25710  -1.826 0.068551 .  
Reason.for.absence9              2.50961    1.64525   1.525 0.127861    
Reason.for.absence10            -1.38623    0.93321  -1.485 0.138118    
Reason.for.absence11            -1.61165    0.97707  -1.649 0.099739 .  
Reason.for.absence12            -3.61717    1.32533  -2.729 0.006593 ** 
Reason.for.absence13            -1.97801    0.85425  -2.316 0.021027 *  
Reason.for.absence14            -3.32432    0.98090  -3.389 0.000762 ***
Reason.for.absence15            -0.87024    1.87247  -0.465 0.642326    
Reason.for.absence16            -6.86905    2.59794  -2.644 0.008474 ** 
Reason.for.absence17            -1.53171    2.59252  -0.591 0.554934    
Reason.for.absence18            -0.20789    1.00844  -0.206 0.836766    
Reason.for.absence19            -0.81656    0.90047  -0.907 0.364978    
Reason.for.absence20            -7.62779    1.87942  -4.059 5.81e-05 ***
Reason.for.absence21            -1.46102    1.33881  -1.091 0.275722    
Reason.for.absence22            -0.32663    0.88390  -0.370 0.711905    
Reason.for.absence23            -5.15410    0.79753  -6.463 2.64e-10 ***
Reason.for.absence24            -0.54855    2.56299  -0.214 0.830622    
Reason.for.absence25            -4.09087    0.89925  -4.549 6.91e-06 ***
Reason.for.absence26            -1.47663    0.90940  -1.624 0.105120    
Reason.for.absence27            -4.94175    0.88175  -5.604 3.62e-08 ***
Reason.for.absence28            -5.69586    0.81330  -7.003 8.98e-12 ***
Month.of.absence2                0.88142    0.59180   1.489 0.137071    
Month.of.absence3                1.43892    0.61833   2.327 0.020395 *  
Month.of.absence4                1.05853    0.90034   1.176 0.240324    
Month.of.absence5                0.03979    0.91919   0.043 0.965490    
Month.of.absence6                0.95497    0.90799   1.052 0.293474    
Month.of.absence7                2.45868    1.10621   2.223 0.026730 *  
Month.of.absence8                1.87651    1.16090   1.616 0.106694    
Month.of.absence9                2.17014    1.15453   1.880 0.060788 .  
Month.of.absence10               1.70371    1.11433   1.529 0.126979    
Month.of.absence11               1.06564    1.04628   1.019 0.308974    
Month.of.absence12               1.78648    0.96418   1.853 0.064548 .  
Day.of.the.week3                 0.22495    0.34200   0.658 0.511037    
Day.of.the.week4                 0.08878    0.34473   0.258 0.796875    
Day.of.the.week5                 0.11849    0.35653   0.332 0.739777    
Day.of.the.week6                -0.18830    0.36319  -0.518 0.604380    
Seasons2                         0.74861    0.84760   0.883 0.377589    
Seasons3                         1.45558    0.76891   1.893 0.058984 .  
Seasons4                         0.39722    0.70809   0.561 0.575089    
Transportation.expense           0.25981    0.14928   1.740 0.082453 .  
Distance.from.Residence.to.Work -0.12857    0.18140  -0.709 0.478838    
Service.time                     0.22001    0.20770   1.059 0.290038    
Age                             -0.26143    0.17197  -1.520 0.129144    
Work.load.Average.day            0.16362    0.14279   1.146 0.252466    
Hit.target                      -0.01859    0.18278  -0.102 0.919051    
Disciplinary.failure1           -0.76155    1.79424  -0.424 0.671444    
Education2                      -0.14898    0.54931  -0.271 0.786351    
Education3                      -0.90364    0.48861  -1.849 0.065044 .  
Education4                      -1.65052    1.79884  -0.918 0.359342    
Son                              0.30184    0.13123   2.300 0.021894 *  
Social.drinker1                  0.18587    0.36431   0.510 0.610168    
Social.smoker1                   0.41938    0.52089   0.805 0.421173    
Pet                             -0.23407    0.17192  -1.362 0.174015    
Weight                           0.07591    1.54838   0.049 0.960923    
Height                           0.04431    0.66029   0.067 0.946530    
Body.mass.index                 -0.15359    1.46924  -0.105 0.916792    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 2.379 on 457 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.561, Adjusted R-squared:  0.5034 
F-statistic: 9.733 on 60 and 457 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

Due to low value of adjusted R square and lower significance of predictors, i tried to add automated interaction. It give me a good R square value and reduce the residuals but the interactions are more than 3k.

```
Call:
lm(formula = Absenteeism.time.in.hours ~ .^2, data = trainData)

Residuals:
   Min     1Q Median     3Q    Max 
  -2.5    0.0    0.0    0.0    2.5 

Coefficients: (981 not defined because of singularities)
                                                         Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
(Intercept)                                             4.544e+04  1.563e+04   2.907  0.00630 **
Reason.for.absence3                                    -7.661e+04  2.679e+04  -2.860  0.00710 **
Reason.for.absence5                                     5.397e+04  1.910e+04   2.825  0.00775 **
Reason.for.absence6                                    -3.851e+04  1.306e+04  -2.950  0.00564 **
Reason.for.absence7                                    -7.240e+02  2.875e+02  -2.518  0.01653 * 
Reason.for.absence8                                     1.230e+04  5.555e+03   2.215  0.03340 * 
Reason.for.absence9                                     1.230e+04  5.555e+03   2.215  0.03340 * 
Reason.for.absence10                                    4.106e+04  1.655e+04   2.481  0.01803 * 
Reason.for.absence11                                   -6.060e+04  2.089e+04  -2.901  0.00639 **
Reason.for.absence12                                    1.750e+04  6.150e+03   2.846  0.00736 **
Reason.for.absence13                                   -1.374e+05  4.993e+04  -2.752  0.00932 **
Reason.for.absence14                                   -2.734e+04  8.978e+03  -3.045  0.00440 **
Reason.for.absence15                                   -3.418e+04  1.144e+04  -2.988  0.00511 **
Reason.for.absence16                                   -2.823e+04  9.312e+03  -3.032  0.00455 **
Reason.for.absence17                                   -2.889e+04  9.804e+03  -2.947  0.00568 **
Reason.for.absence18                                   -9.907e+04  3.277e+04  -3.023  0.00466 **
Reason.for.absence19                                   -5.689e+04  1.933e+04  -2.943  0.00573 **
Reason.for.absence20                                   -6.395e+04  2.133e+04  -2.998  0.00497 **
Reason.for.absence21                                   -7.894e+04  2.717e+04  -2.905  0.00632 **
Reason.for.absence22                                    1.660e+06  6.382e+05   2.601  0.01353 * 
Reason.for.absence23                                    1.244e+04  6.789e+03   1.833  0.07536 . 
Reason.for.absence24                                   -5.574e+04  1.879e+04  -2.966  0.00541 **
Reason.for.absence25                                    4.663e+03  1.590e+03   2.932  0.00589 **
Reason.for.absence26                                   -1.971e+04  6.264e+03  -3.146  0.00337 **
Reason.for.absence27                                   -6.624e+04  2.221e+04  -2.983  0.00517 **
Reason.for.absence28                                   -4.295e+04  1.460e+04  -2.942  0.00575 **
Month.of.absence2                                      -6.860e+04  2.381e+04  -2.881  0.00673 **
Month.of.absence3                                      -4.356e+04  1.493e+04  -2.918  0.00612 **
Month.of.absence4                                      -3.054e+03  1.196e+03  -2.553  0.01518 * 
Month.of.absence5                                      -4.884e+04  1.745e+04  -2.798  0.00830 **
Month.of.absence6                                      -1.420e+03  8.899e+02  -1.595  0.11959   
Month.of.absence7                                      -5.203e+04  1.796e+04  -2.896  0.00647 **
Month.of.absence8                                      -4.492e+03  1.749e+03  -2.569  0.01462 * 
Month.of.absence9                                      -1.913e+03  7.176e+02  -2.666  0.01153 * 
Month.of.absence10                                      1.324e+04  4.522e+03   2.928  0.00596 **
Month.of.absence11                                     -3.700e+03  1.467e+03  -2.523  0.01634 * 
Month.of.absence12                                     -3.260e+03  1.297e+03  -2.514  0.01671 * 
Day.of.the.week3                                       -1.182e+04  4.541e+03  -2.602  0.01349 * 
Day.of.the.week4                                        9.954e+02  3.746e+02   2.657  0.01178 * 
Day.of.the.week5                                        4.068e+02  1.498e+02   2.715  0.01022 * 
Day.of.the.week6                                       -2.288e+01  2.250e+01  -1.017  0.31611   
Seasons2                                                5.000e-01  1.610e+00   0.311  0.75796   
Seasons3                                                1.000e+00  1.054e+00   0.949  0.34920   
Seasons4                                               -1.000e+00  1.217e+00  -0.822  0.41679   
Transportation.expense                                  2.641e+04  9.451e+03   2.795  0.00838 **
Distance.from.Residence.to.Work                        -8.374e+03  2.955e+03  -2.834  0.00759 **
Service.time                                            2.751e+04  9.591e+03   2.868  0.00695 **
Age                                                     6.305e+03  2.487e+03   2.536  0.01585 * 
Work.load.Average.day                                   1.179e+03  4.106e+02   2.872  0.00688 **
Hit.target                                             -4.706e+02  1.622e+02  -2.901  0.00639 **
Disciplinary.failure1                                   8.626e+03  2.695e+03   3.200  0.00292 **
Education2                                              1.491e+04  5.099e+03   2.924  0.00603 **
Education3                                             -2.001e+04  6.578e+03  -3.043  0.00442 **
Education4                                              6.296e+05  2.411e+05   2.611  0.01321 * 
Son                                                     2.008e+02  6.406e+01   3.134  0.00348 **
Social.drinker1                                         2.040e+03  6.412e+02   3.182  0.00306 **
Social.smoker1                                          7.115e+02  2.453e+02   2.901  0.00639 **
Pet                                                    -3.460e+02  1.344e+02  -2.575  0.01440 * 
Weight                                                  2.866e+02  5.899e+02   0.486  0.63007   
Height                                                 -1.068e+03  4.698e+02  -2.274  0.02923 * 
Body.mass.index                                         5.374e+02  5.141e+02   1.045  0.30297   
Reason.for.absence3:Month.of.absence2                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence5:Month.of.absence2                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence6:Month.of.absence2                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence7:Month.of.absence2                   4.696e+04  1.665e+04   2.820  0.00785 **
Reason.for.absence8:Month.of.absence2                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence9:Month.of.absence2                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence10:Month.of.absence2                  3.832e+04  1.324e+04   2.895  0.00649 **
Reason.for.absence11:Month.of.absence2                  1.720e+05  5.997e+04   2.868  0.00695 **
Reason.for.absence12:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence13:Month.of.absence2                  6.542e+04  2.260e+04   2.894  0.00650 **
Reason.for.absence14:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence15:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence16:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence17:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence18:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence19:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence20:Month.of.absence2                  7.802e+04  2.654e+04   2.940  0.00579 **
Reason.for.absence21:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence22:Month.of.absence2                  1.966e+04  6.250e+03   3.145  0.00338 **
Reason.for.absence23:Month.of.absence2                  6.562e+04  2.267e+04   2.895  0.00650 **
Reason.for.absence24:Month.of.absence2                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence25:Month.of.absence2                  1.463e+04  5.231e+03   2.796  0.00835 **
Reason.for.absence26:Month.of.absence2                  6.663e+04  2.276e+04   2.927  0.00598 **
Reason.for.absence27:Month.of.absence2                  6.653e+04  2.298e+04   2.895  0.00650 **
Reason.for.absence28:Month.of.absence2                  6.595e+04  2.279e+04   2.894  0.00650 **
Reason.for.absence3:Month.of.absence3                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence5:Month.of.absence3                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence6:Month.of.absence3                   8.536e+03  2.808e+03   3.040  0.00446 **
Reason.for.absence7:Month.of.absence3                   1.911e+04  6.735e+03   2.837  0.00752 **
Reason.for.absence8:Month.of.absence3                  -5.313e+04  1.956e+04  -2.717  0.01017 * 
Reason.for.absence9:Month.of.absence3                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence10:Month.of.absence3                  4.355e+04  1.588e+04   2.742  0.00957 **
Reason.for.absence11:Month.of.absence3                  6.423e+04  2.206e+04   2.912  0.00622 **
Reason.for.absence12:Month.of.absence3                 -4.145e+04  1.461e+04  -2.836  0.00754 **
Reason.for.absence13:Month.of.absence3                  3.752e+04  1.273e+04   2.948  0.00567 **
Reason.for.absence14:Month.of.absence3                  1.287e+04  4.543e+03   2.832  0.00762 **
Reason.for.absence15:Month.of.absence3                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence16:Month.of.absence3                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence17:Month.of.absence3                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence18:Month.of.absence3                  1.202e+04  4.169e+03   2.883  0.00670 **
Reason.for.absence19:Month.of.absence3                  9.804e+04  3.453e+04   2.839  0.00748 **
Reason.for.absence20:Month.of.absence3                  4.404e+04  1.497e+04   2.941  0.00576 **
Reason.for.absence21:Month.of.absence3                  6.880e+04  2.305e+04   2.984  0.00515 **
Reason.for.absence22:Month.of.absence3                  5.464e+04  1.893e+04   2.887  0.00663 **
Reason.for.absence23:Month.of.absence3                  3.812e+04  1.294e+04   2.947  0.00568 **
Reason.for.absence24:Month.of.absence3                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence25:Month.of.absence3                 -4.291e+03  2.684e+03  -1.599  0.11892   
Reason.for.absence26:Month.of.absence3                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence27:Month.of.absence3                  3.913e+04  1.330e+04   2.942  0.00575 **
Reason.for.absence28:Month.of.absence3                  3.855e+04  1.308e+04   2.946  0.00569 **
Reason.for.absence3:Month.of.absence4                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence5:Month.of.absence4                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence6:Month.of.absence4                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence7:Month.of.absence4                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence8:Month.of.absence4                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence9:Month.of.absence4                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence10:Month.of.absence4                 -9.741e+04  3.542e+04  -2.750  0.00936 **
Reason.for.absence11:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence12:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence13:Month.of.absence4                  2.601e+03  1.085e+03   2.397  0.02200 * 
Reason.for.absence14:Month.of.absence4                 -2.856e+04  9.594e+03  -2.977  0.00526 **
Reason.for.absence15:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence16:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence17:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence18:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence19:Month.of.absence4                  5.713e+04  2.049e+04   2.788  0.00852 **
Reason.for.absence20:Month.of.absence4                  5.755e+03  1.883e+03   3.057  0.00426 **
Reason.for.absence21:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence22:Month.of.absence4                 -1.401e+06  5.376e+05  -2.605  0.01338 * 
Reason.for.absence23:Month.of.absence4                 -7.467e+02  2.594e+02  -2.878  0.00677 **
Reason.for.absence24:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence25:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence26:Month.of.absence4                  4.042e+03  1.273e+03   3.176  0.00311 **
Reason.for.absence27:Month.of.absence4                 -1.778e+03  6.852e+02  -2.594  0.01375 * 
Reason.for.absence28:Month.of.absence4                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence3:Month.of.absence5                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence5:Month.of.absence5                  -4.875e+04  1.641e+04  -2.970  0.00534 **
Reason.for.absence6:Month.of.absence5                   7.054e+04  2.496e+04   2.827  0.00773 **
Reason.for.absence7:Month.of.absence5                   5.239e+04  1.931e+04   2.713  0.01028 * 
Reason.for.absence8:Month.of.absence5                  -4.377e+04  1.553e+04  -2.819  0.00788 **
Reason.for.absence9:Month.of.absence5                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence10:Month.of.absence5                 -2.085e+04  7.934e+03  -2.627  0.01269 * 
Reason.for.absence11:Month.of.absence5                  1.446e+04  5.346e+03   2.705  0.01047 * 
Reason.for.absence12:Month.of.absence5                 -1.809e+04  5.718e+03  -3.163  0.00322 **
Reason.for.absence13:Month.of.absence5                  5.085e+04  1.808e+04   2.813  0.00799 **
Reason.for.absence14:Month.of.absence5                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence15:Month.of.absence5                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence16:Month.of.absence5                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence17:Month.of.absence5                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence18:Month.of.absence5                  1.564e+05  5.199e+04   3.009  0.00484 **
Reason.for.absence19:Month.of.absence5                  1.179e+05  4.202e+04   2.806  0.00814 **
Reason.for.absence20:Month.of.absence5                  5.473e+04  1.943e+04   2.817  0.00791 **
Reason.for.absence21:Month.of.absence5                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence22:Month.of.absence5                 -1.312e+06  5.051e+05  -2.597  0.01366 * 
Reason.for.absence23:Month.of.absence5                  5.121e+04  1.822e+04   2.810  0.00805 **
Reason.for.absence24:Month.of.absence5                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence25:Month.of.absence5                  6.797e+04  2.304e+04   2.951  0.00562 **
Reason.for.absence26:Month.of.absence5                  3.132e+04  1.081e+04   2.898  0.00644 **
Reason.for.absence27:Month.of.absence5                  5.432e+04  1.929e+04   2.816  0.00793 **
Reason.for.absence28:Month.of.absence5                  5.175e+04  1.836e+04   2.819  0.00788 **
Reason.for.absence3:Month.of.absence6                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence5:Month.of.absence6                  -5.704e+04  1.880e+04  -3.035  0.00452 **
Reason.for.absence6:Month.of.absence6                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence7:Month.of.absence6                  -5.138e+04  1.670e+04  -3.077  0.00405 **
Reason.for.absence8:Month.of.absence6                  -1.437e+04  5.287e+03  -2.718  0.01014 * 
Reason.for.absence9:Month.of.absence6                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence10:Month.of.absence6                 -3.792e+04  1.316e+04  -2.882  0.00671 **
Reason.for.absence11:Month.of.absence6                 -1.584e+04  5.474e+03  -2.894  0.00650 **
Reason.for.absence12:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence13:Month.of.absence6                  5.136e+04  1.951e+04   2.632  0.01254 * 
Reason.for.absence14:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence15:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence16:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence17:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence18:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence19:Month.of.absence6                  1.011e+05  3.666e+04   2.758  0.00917 **
Reason.for.absence20:Month.of.absence6                  8.580e+03  2.933e+03   2.925  0.00600 **
Reason.for.absence21:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence22:Month.of.absence6                 -1.318e+06  5.064e+05  -2.602  0.01349 * 
Reason.for.absence23:Month.of.absence6                 -9.685e+02  3.283e+02  -2.950  0.00563 **
Reason.for.absence24:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence25:Month.of.absence6                 -1.049e+04  3.348e+03  -3.133  0.00349 **
Reason.for.absence26:Month.of.absence6                 -5.073e+04  1.828e+04  -2.775  0.00879 **
Reason.for.absence27:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence28:Month.of.absence6                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence3:Month.of.absence7                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence5:Month.of.absence7                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence6:Month.of.absence7                   1.017e+03  2.343e+03   0.434  0.66694   
Reason.for.absence7:Month.of.absence7                  -5.014e+03  1.777e+03  -2.821  0.00783 **
Reason.for.absence8:Month.of.absence7                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence9:Month.of.absence7                          NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence10:Month.of.absence7                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence11:Month.of.absence7                  1.911e+04  6.310e+03   3.029  0.00459 **
Reason.for.absence12:Month.of.absence7                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence13:Month.of.absence7                  8.641e+04  3.107e+04   2.781  0.00867 **
Reason.for.absence14:Month.of.absence7                  2.445e+04  7.985e+03   3.062  0.00421 **
Reason.for.absence15:Month.of.absence7                 -4.872e+03  2.925e+03  -1.666  0.10467   
Reason.for.absence16:Month.of.absence7                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
Reason.for.absence17:Month.of.absence7                         NA         NA      NA       NA   
 [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 1264 rows ]
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.8605 on 35 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.9956,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.935 
F-statistic: 16.43 on 482 and 35 DF,  p-value: 1.228e-15
```

I am new to stats and regression. SO what is the correct way to perform this. How should I choose predictors and interaction to add to my model.

Answer (score 0):

One approach you could use is to group some of the levels of the categories together into an "other" section.  For example, in the first regression, there are several "reason for absence" coefficients with large p-values.  These could be grouped to simplify the model and to ensure you have enough observations of each level to get a good estimate of the coefficient. (Sometimes with a lot of levels of a category, you do not have enough observations in some of the levels to really include them separately. Without more information, I am guessing that this may be a factor here.)

Additionally, you could group the months into quarters to reduce the complexity there. Then, if you would like to add interaction terms, there will not be as many, although there will still be a lot.

Of course, the trade off here is that you will lose specificity.  Depending on your application, this may or may not be okay.